# Saving UILabel information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, save

I am working on the next update for my app and I am trying to save the information on my UILabels when the app closes or switches page. This is what I have, every time you hit a button, it will update my UILabel to add 1 to the previous number, i.e value = 0 but when button pressed = 1, however it seems to reset every time I reload the page, I was wondering if their was a way to save that information, and if so how could you do that? Below is some of my code.

Header File

```
//Here I have created two labels that get updated when button pressed.
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

}
//Here I have created two variables that correspond to the change in number.
@property (nonatomic) int i;
@property (nonatomic) int s;
```

Implementation File:

```
//Here I have instantiated the two variables in my viewWillAppear method.
- (void)viewWillAppear{

self.i = 0;
self.s = 0;

}

//Here I have my button that changes the value of the label.
-(IBAction)randomButton {

self.i++;
[self->label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.i]];
```

Thanks in advanced. Recap: How do I save the value of my UILabels, but allow them to still be updated by adding 1 to the value when a button is pressed? But I want to be able to save that value and come back to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Updated:
Page 1 (this is my homepage)

[image]

Page 2 (my stats page/ game page)

[image]

I want to be able to save that number, which is a UILabel. However when I play for a bit and get high numbers and then press back in the top left of the 2nd page, and then press start agian on the first page, the numbers revert back to 0. How can i make them keep their value?

Here are my problems (in .h) :
[image]

Here are my problems (in .m) :
[image]

Updated again: My .h has no problems now, but my .m has lots:
[image]

This is my AppDelegate.h
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any problem with using NSUserDefaults? That way it would be saved across views and when app closes.

Add to your button action the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setValue:aValue forKey:@"savedString1];
```

The first line is for quick access. Then you store the value (aValue) under the string of "savedString1".

Then, depending on when you wanted it to be loaded again, you would do:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *returnAValue = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"savedString1"];
```

This would then declare a new NSString with the previous value. You could include this in viewDidLoad.

You can store integers / other stuff too - just use `integerForKey` instead of valueForKey when loading, and declare an integer.

Hope it helps?

Comment: when i implement this into the app, I get the problem "undleclared identifer" for aValue?

Comment: Replace 'aValue' with the name of your string / integer / whatever.

Comment: Also remember that if it is an integer, you will want to have your integer pre-declared (int randomText = whatever), then replace aValue with the name of your variable you want to save (randomText, right?). When loading, you will want to use integerForKey instead of value. Hope this works for you!

Comment: So I, implemented the top code into the button, however I'm having a problem with the return code, and how to implement this. Because its saying returnAValue is an undeclared identifier as well?

Comment: Put this under your button action:                             NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setValue:randomText forKey:@"savedString1];                And this in your viewDidLoad or wherever you want it to be loaded:      NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int randomText = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"savedString1"];               Then use your randomText for whatever. If you have any more problems let me know. Remember that you need to replace it with whatever you need, then use these integers later.

Answer (score 1):

edit your AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

//add thist 2 properties
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger counti;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger counts;

@end
```

then edit your code for your viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [self->label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appDelegate.counti]];
    [self->label2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appDelegate.counts]];
}

-(IBAction)randomButton {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.counti = appDelegate.counti+1 ;
    [self->label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appDelegate.counti]];


}
```

it should work

Comment: you don't have to put the top code,  i just make a example :)

Comment: It says that there is no known class method for selector "numberWithIntValue"? @adali

Comment: numberWithInt   or  numberWithInteger,  sorry  typo

Comment: its not saving when i change the page on the app, and then go back? I have inserted what you told me, exactly? @adali

Comment: can you put more images for the operation you described? i don't exactly understand "change the page" & "go back"?

Comment: I updated the original question, so you can have a look. Thank for doing this btw.

Comment: it says that the property with "retain" attribute must be of object type?

Comment: it's not retain , it's assign

Comment: oh,  you may write thist  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger counti;

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign)   this may be right ,  &  what's the name of your *AppDelegate.h?  you may import the *Appdelegate.h

Comment: I edited the question, my .h has no problems now but the .m has lots, take a look.

Comment: Updated the question with the app delegate.h

Comment: this 2 line should add to AppDelegate.h   not in ViewController.h
```@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger counti;```
```@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger counts;```

Comment: so revert my veiwcontroller.h to normal?

Comment: ok were down to one error, instead of 10, on the line "AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];" it says an error saying "expected identifier"?

Comment: Ok, its working, however, is it possible to make the number first appear before you press the button, because right now what is happening is, i load the page, i press the button, it counts, then i press back, then i press start and i'm back at the stats page, but the numbers appaer to be 0, but if i press a button they change to the previous. is their a way to make the previous number show up right away instead of having to press the button?

Comment: oh  the function i spelled wrong, should be  ```- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}```    i edited my answer

Comment: Sweet it works!!! Now however, I know i'm asking you a ton of questions, but, what if the app completley quits?

Comment: you want restore the number if user open the app again?

Comment: like if they completely quit the app, so it had to relaunch, is it possible?

Comment: of course, you should follow thist article http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding

Comment: i'm not sure how to implement this into my app, any ideas? @adali